# C++ STD::MAP Complex Key Search

Tags: c++, stdmap

I have limited access to libraries so although using boost::multi_index would solve my issue it is something that I cannot use.

My current map setup is: 
The structure contains a fair amount of information in it such as an INT that I will also need to search by. What I was hoping was a structure such as  so that I can search by int or string and return the structure values. I am assuming that I am going to have to write the key but, was coming here for other suggestions.

Ideas?

Comment: You’ve essentially given the answer: write it yourself.

Comment: What's wrong with boost again?

Comment: You can use std::pair<string,int> and add your own predicate for searching.

you can hold two different maps that points to the same objects.

maybe you can hash the string and the int into a single key?

Comment: @AJG85:  Boost isn't an option in many environments for a variety of reasonable reasons.

Comment: @AJG85 - nothing wrong with Boost. but not everyone can use it.

Comment: I was just curious what the reason was as "limited access" could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused.  You seem to be saying that you have a construct like this:

(psudocode)

```
struct Gizmo
{
  Gizmo(int foo, string bar) : foo_(foo), bar_(bar) {};
  int foo_;
  string bar_;
};
Gizmo make_gizmo(int foo, string bar) { return Gizmo(foo,bar); }
std::map<string, Gizmo> my_gizmos;

my_gizmos["aaa"] = make_gizmo(1,"hello");
my_gizmos["bbb"] = make_gizmo(2,"there");
```

...and you want to be able to search for `Gizmo`s by the value of `foo_`?

In that case, you have 2 main options.

1) Just write a custom functor yourself (again psudocude):

```
struct match_foo : public std::unary_function<...>
{
  match_foo(int foo) : foo_(foo) {};
  bool operator()(map<string,Gizmo>::const_iterator it) const
  {
    return it->second.foo_ == foo_;
  } 
private:
  int foo_;
};

map<string,Gizmo>::const_iterator that = find_if(my_gizmos.begin(), my_gizmos.end(), match_foo(2));
};
```

2) Create an index of the `foo_` values, mapping back to the `Gizmo` in the main `map`.  This map might look something like this
...
a

```
   map<int,map<string,Gizmo>::const_iterator> foo_index;
```

...which you would maintain any time you update the main map, `my_gizmos`.

Comment: Is it really wise to use the iterator? they can get invalidated when you update the map<string,Gizmo>.

Comment: +1: For option 1 that is ... @Manic his caveat about needing to maintain any time you update map is in reference to that.

Comment: @AJG85: ah OK I thought that he meant only about adding it to the maps and deleting from the two maps.

Comment: @ManicQin:  Existing iterators dont become invalidated in a map, unless you delete them.

Comment: I think you would probably end up making that a `typedef` and then creating a `foo_index` from the current `my_gizmos` map on stack every time you search with some kind of locking to prevent the gizmo map from changing during the search scope ... it probably gets more sketchy that's why I'd prefer option 1 ;)

Comment: Option 1 is definitely better unless you have compelling reasons why it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

If your searches actually are windowing queries(meaning you must return values in [param0_0, peram0_1]x[param1_0, param1_2]x...) or so, then you can use range tree structure for efficiency.